# Incremental Numbering appending to existing filename or in new column whenever new item is added in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, library, office-365-developer, auto-increment

I require your assistance where I want to create auto incremental numbering to file and folder name where whenever a folder/file is added to library. Filename should get appended with incremental number from the previous one. Numbering should be incremental as per their relevancy in particular folder.

I was researching and tried to refer some posts where it suggests to create SPD Workflow but could not come with up actions and logic.

Reference Articles:

1. [Automumber Custom List Field](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/867bcacd-d378-411a-849a-fc040de9e5da/automumber-custom-list-field)
2. [Auto create filename using metadata when uploading a document](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8854540d-6a6b-409e-b6ce-1ee57bfa7df5/auto-create-filename-using-metadata-when-uploading-a-document).

Is this something possible in SharePoint Online?

If yes, please help me through the steps.